# change snap netbeans to spanish (snap get netbeans saids it has no configuration options)

Tags: snap, netbeans

In older versions we change netbeans.conf adding in "netbeans_default_options= ..." the following: "-J- Duser.language=es"

Snap has `get` and `set`... but:

```
$ sudo snap get netbeans
```

shows the error:

```
error: snap "netbeans" has no configuration
```

**Q**: How I can change the language in the snap version of NetBeans?

---

> My ubuntu: 20.04 
> Netbeans instaled: installed:          12.0            (30) 462MB classic

Answer (score 0):

Last shot:

## Fist I saw without doing anything

$ sudo unsquashfs -v -i -ls  /var/lib/snapd/snaps/netbeans_30.snap

## then I unsquash the thing.

$ sudo unsquashfs -v -i -li  /var/lib/snapd/snaps/netbeans_30.snap

#change "netbeans_default_options=" adding '-J-Duser.language=es'

## make the thing again...

sudo mksquashfs squashfs-root netbeans_30.snap

#umount the thing...
sudo umount /snap/netbeans/30

#copy the thing
sudo cp netbeans_30.snap /var/lib/snapd/snaps/netbeans_30.snap

#reboot (I did not want to fight against the mount...)

## check the state of the work

$ cat /snap/netbeans/30/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf | grep "netbeans_default_options="

netbeans_default_options="-J-XX:+UseStringDeduplication -J-Xss2m -J-Duser.language=es -J-Djdk.gtk.version=2.2 -J-Dplugin.manager.install.global=false
...
another stuff here...
...
exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED -J-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions"

the changes remain... but netbeans.... still is in english...   buahhhh